# Does a standalone EASA Multi-Engine Instrument Rating exist?

Tags: easa-regulations, multi-engine, cpl, type-ratings, instrument-rating

I'm starting an A320 type rating in a couple of months, but my MEP/IR is expiring before that. The pre-entry requirements were only a ME IR. Got me wondering: can I just revalidate my ME IR and let my MEP expire? In other words: is there such a thing as a **standalone ME IR** (meaning no class or type rating that goes with it)? Thanks and happy landings!

Comment: I think you need to modify your question to include jusitriction (FAA, EASA, CASA, JAA, etc) Without this information, your question is unanswerable.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I updated my question.

Comment: What is a TR? What country are you talking about?

Comment: @Terry TR is Type Rating and country shouldn't matter. As long it's under EASA regulations it should be valid in all its member states (which is where I'll be operating).

Comment: If your question is  "do standalone ME IR exist?" you should write it as is in the title. The title helps navigate through questions and have an idea of what is asked about the subject. Many question may exists speaking of multiengine instrument rating,thus the title should be more precise.

Comment: @ManuH thanks for the suggestion

Comment: MEP? Multi engine propellor? There's no difference between multi-engine ratings depending on engine type.

Comment: @jwenting that's not at all what I'm stating or asking.

Comment: it's exactly what you're asking as written.

Comment: It's possible to revalidate ME/IR every second year in the sim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was just published in CAP1855 from the CAA a few days ago, which may answer your question:

> Instrument Rating validity, revalidation and renewal for aeroplanes and helicopters
>
> To revalidate, you must hold a valid relevant class or type rating, unless the IR revalidation is combined with the renewal of the relevant class or type rating; no “empty” IR to be endorsed
>
> The UK CAA has deferred this requirement until 10 January 2020 as stated in ORS4 N.1329.
>
> References: Subpart G, FCL.625, FCL.625(A), FCL.625(H))

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer this from a USA perspective.

If you hold a multi-engine rating and/or an instrument rating, they DO NOT expire. Currency determines if they are useable.

If you are getting a new rating (type rating) when that is issued it revalidates the ME and the Instrument rating. You are then current with both and the new type rating. The ME and Instrument ratings are NOT airplane specific, unless a type rating is required for the airplane.

Roger G, ATP (with many type ratings) CFII A&P IA AD.